# Get input job value to use it in a command execution Rundeck

Tags: parameters, scripting, rundeck

My Rundeck detail:

```
Rundeck version: 2.10.7
install type: rpm
OS Name/version: CentOS 6.7
DB Type/version: h2
```

I want to get all data from a required input data and use it in a script execution as follows:

```
/home/user/script.sh INPUTDATA1 INPUTDATA2
```

I tried next variables but it does not work:

```
/home/user/script.sh $RD_OPTION_1 $RD_OPTION_2
```

What should I do?

I think about modifying the `script.sh` to get those input options as `@option.1@` but I'd prefer to use the scripts without modifying them.

Answer (score 0):

The convention is whatever is the field name that should be given after RD_OPTION_. For example if message is field name it will be $RD_OPTION_MESSAGE. Make sure your you are passing right names, based on your question, it expects field names 1 and 2. You can read more on this [documentation](http://rundeck.org/2.0.0/manual/job-options.html)